# Como receber notificações dentro de uma activity

Tags: java, android, firebase

Consigo enviar uma notificação do Firebase para o meu App  mas ao  Abrir essa mesma notificação não abre dentro da Activity que eu quero.
Como eu faço para direccionar essa notificação para a activity de modo que eu possa ver a mensagem enviada do Firebase?

Comment: Vc ja perguntou isso [sua pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/260885/n%C3%A3o-consigo-abrir-uma-mensagem-enviada-pelo-firebase/260917#260917)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro você tem que ir no seu AndroidManifest.xml e adicionar um action para sua activity.
Exemplo:

```
  <activity android:name=".ActivityPrincipal">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="ActivityPrincipal" />
            </intent-filter>
```

Dentro da sua classe responsável pelo serviço de mensagem do firebase:

```
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        Map<String,String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
        final LocalBroadcastManager broadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);

        if(remoteMessage.getNotification() != null)
        {

            Intent intent = new Intent("Notificacao");
            intent.putExtra("img",data.get("imagem"));
            System.out.println("IMAGEM:"+data.get("imagem"));
            broadcastManager.sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    }
```

Nesse caso,estou pegando o link de uma imagem pela notificação.

Dentro da Activity que você quer abrir a mensagem:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(myReceiver,
                new IntentFilter("Notificacao"));


    }

 private BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


            System.out.println("RECEBE!!!!");
            ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgview);
                Bundle dados  =intent.getExtras();
            String url = "http://192.168.0.12/img/"+dados.getString("img");
            System.out.println(url);
            Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(url).into(img);
            TextView txtmsg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewmensagem);
            TextView txttitulo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewtitulo);



            txtmsg.setText(dados.getString("mensagem"));
            txttitulo.setText(dados.getString("titulo"));
        }
    };
```

Dentro do BroadcastReceiver,você faz o que precisa ser mostrado.

Ultima etapa é enviar a notificação pelo firebase,informando qual activity tem que ser aberta ao clicar na notificação ( no nosso caso,a ActivityPrincipal)

agora na api do firebase,você tem que colocar este parâmetro:

```
click_action = "ActivityPrincipal"
```